# Problems syncing to GitHub

Tags: github

I am trying to push data to remote repo. Keep going round in circles.
I think that i have made a small mistake which is holding me back.

```
p@LAPTOP-O5L8LHSL MINGW64 ~/DataScience (master)
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
To https://github.com/adkin1988/datasciencecoursera.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/adkin1988/datasciencecoursera.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

hp@LAPTOP-O5L8LHSL MINGW64 ~/DataScience (master)
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

Comment: Did you try `git pull origin master` followed by `git push`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to define which remote branch is related with your current local branch. see the last line of the code you have pasted